# После звонка с приложения, статус бар меняет цвет

Tags: ios, swift

так я настроил `StatusBar` и `NavigationBar` в `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

```
static func setParamsBars(){
let bounds = UIScreen.main.bounds

UIApplication.shared.statusBarView?.backgroundColor = .clear

UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.white
UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.white, NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "SFUIDisplay-Regular", size: 18)!]

let imagebar : UIImage = UIImage(color: UIColor(red: 136.0/255.0, green: 136.0/255.0, blue: 136.0/255.0, alpha: 0.8), size: CGSize(width: bounds.size.width, height: 84))!
UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(imagebar, for: .default)
UINavigationBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage()
UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = true
}
```

мой первый скрин кода все ок:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

теперь я звоню с приложения:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

когда возвращаюсь после звонка обратно в приложение то статус бар уже такого цвета: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я понятия не имею что происходит, суть в том что статус бар у меня прозрачного цвета. Мб какие то слои накладываются. Буду рад любой помощи.

EDIT:

Проблема на iphone5 и iPhone 5s. На 6 iPhone все норм.

UPDATE: 
скрины `Debug View Hierarchy`
До звонка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

после звонка: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попробуйте [посмотреть тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43595514/uiviewcontroller-in-call-status-bar-issue).

Comment: Попробуйте перенести код UIApplication.shared.statusBarView?.backgroundColor = .clear в applicationWillEnterForeground. Вероятнее всего после звонка, аппа возвращает дефолтный цвет статус бара, и не попадает в Ваш setParamsBars  метод. Отсюда и другой цвет.

Comment: @VitaliEller, к сожалению не помогло, в методе который вы указали я вызвал setParamsBars. Безрезультатно.

Comment: @Denis, да,  такая же проблемы, все варианты реализовал у себя, ни один не подошел к сожалению.

Comment: Покажите Вашу `Debug View Hierarchy`

Comment: @VAndrJ, Обновил.